# Getting unexpected behavior when examining the IsChecked property of a Checkbox

Tags: wpf, checkbox, ischecked

We have 6 `CheckBox`es on a user control. We want to be able to determine, whether or not each of the 6 boxes are checked. We tried doing this in this event in the code behind:

```
private const short Black = 1;
private const short White = 32;
private const short Asian = 2;
private const short Islander = 8;
private const short AmInd = 4;
private const short Alask = 16;

private void RaceCheckboxes_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    short race = 0;

    if (cbAlask.IsChecked == true)
    {
        race += Alask;
    }
    if (cbAmInd.IsChecked == true)
    {
        race += AmInd;
    }
    if (cbIslander.IsChecked == true)
    {
        race += Islander;
    }
    if (cbAsian.IsChecked == true)
    {
        race += Asian;
    }
    if (cbWht.IsChecked == true)
    {
        race += White;
    }
    if (cbBlack.IsChecked == true)
    {
        race += Black;
    }

    atr.Race = race;
}
```

The thing I don't understand is this. When the user clicks on the checkbox named cbWht, it entered this event and all 6 of the checkboxes `IsChecked` property were true. Why is that? Only 1 of them was checked.

Comment: Can you post your XAML?

Comment: I discovered that the problem was the XAML. It was being data bound to the same field in the database. Change one, and it affected all six. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Clicked` event instead of the `Checked` event. I.e. `RaceCheckboxes_Clicked`.

Comment: What's the difference between the Clicked and the Checked events, as far as the Checkbox in WPF goes?